# adding yeoman to github pages blog

Tags: jekyll, yeoman, github-pages

I had a blog running at morenoh149.github.io I attempted to add yeoman to my workflow using [jekyllrb generator](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb). I followed the instructions by creating a new yeoman project, and copying over all the generated files and structure to my blog. But now github pages isn't picking up the blog. https://github.com/morenoh149/morenoh149.github.io

Anyone know how github pages works? the docs are sparse.
I changed the source in my yml file to app/ as well. So now when I run `jekyll` locally it works. But when I push to github pages it's not.

**_config.yml**

```
# Jekyll configuration precedence:
# 1. Gruntfile task
# 2. config.build.yml
# 3. config.yml

name: morenoh149.blog.yeoman
url: morenoh149.github.io
description: Harry Moreno has a blog
author:
  name: Harry Moreno
  email: morenoh149@gmail.com

# Grunt handles images and assets.
exclude: ['img', 'css', 'js', 'fonts',
          '**.png', '**.jpg', '**.jpeg', '**.gif', '**.webp', '**.svg', '**.ico']

include: ['.htaccess']
source: app

# _config.build.yml sets future and show_drafts to false on `grunt build`
future: true
show_drafts: true

# Markdown library
markdown: redcarpet
#   extensions: ['fenced_code_blocks', 'smart']

pygments: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like GitHub Pages is serving files from your site (for instance, http://morenoh149.github.io/app/ is [an html file with a single paragraph element](http://cl.ly/image/2k3f1G1P2k3d)) but it's not serving them properly with all the Jekyll magic.

It turns out that [GitHub Pages will override the `source` setting](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#configuring-jekyll) in the config file. This means that while you've specified `source: app`, it's looking at your top-level directory for content.

The solution is to move the contents of your `app` directory into your top-level directory.

Comment: I'm not using any plugins. This is frustrating because I've also installed the `github-pages` gem and am able to run my blog locally. But even with your suggested edit I'm not able to get ghps to serve my blog. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try adding `_site/` to your .gitignore file. GitHub Pages tries to generate your site to that directory, but since it's already there, maybe it's running into conflicts. This is recommended in the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/) and it's been [working for me](https://github.com/nicksuch/nicksuch.github.io/blob/master/.gitignore).

You'll also need to delete that `_site` folder and its contents (don't worry, Jekyll will re-generate it for you).

Comment: figured it out. https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#configuring-jekyll the `source` var is overridden on deploy. Add this to your answer and I'll award you the points :)

Comment: Edits made. Congrats on figuring it out and good luck getting your blog published!